# Замена с помощью регулярных выражений python

Tags: python, регулярные-выражения, re

как с помощью регулярных выражений заменить строку

```
<MUTATION value=123>123</MUTATION> has increased <EFFECT>something something</EFFECT>
```

на

```
@MUTATION has increased @EFFECT
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот регулярка, надо только опитонить:

```js
var s = "<MUTATION value=123>123</MUTATION> has increased <EFFECT>something something</EFFECT>"
console.log(s.replace(/<(\w+)[^>]*>((?!<\/\1>).)*<\/\1>/g, "@$1"))
```

Опитонил: https://ideone.com/TNCgnk

```
import re

print(re.sub(r"<(\w+)[^>]*>((?!<\/\1>).)*<\/\1>", r"@\1", input()))
```

Comment: `re.sub(r"<(\w+).+\1>", r"@\1", s)` дает тот же результат

Comment: @SergFSM, только `.+?`, а не `.+`. Но вообще, верно. Стоит ответом запостить.